# CSS Overflow problems with fixed position divs

Tags: html, css

So this problem has come up and been solved probably 1000 times by now ([Scroll part of content in fixed position container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154250/scroll-part-of-content-in-fixed-position-container), [child div height 100% inside position: fixed div + overflow auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883794/child-div-height-100-inside-position-fixed-div-overflow-auto)) but I can't seem to get my CSS to behave.

I am trying to create a popup div that has a scroll-able interior.  I have a dark grey div that should cover the entire window and centered in the window should be a greenish div.  The inner div needs to have a margin and be sized to fit it's content, unless the content is too big and then it needs a scroll bar.

I can't get the scrolling to work.  I've tried specifying max width/height but those seem to get ignored.

**HTML:**

```
<div class='PopupPanelBG'>
    <div class='PopupPanel'>
        <div>
            <div style='width: 1000px;'>some stuff that is really big</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div
```

**CSS:**

```css
.PopupPanelBG {
    display: table;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.PopupPanel {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.PopupPanel>div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0.9;
    background-color: #e1efbb;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 30px;
    overflow : auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QbmdK/

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? Where the X can overflow, but the Y can't? http://jsfiddle.net/Agony/QbmdK/23/

Comment: So setting max width/height to a fixed pixel value seems to work.  Why can't I set it to a %?  I.E. make the inner div no bigger than 95% of the screen?

Comment: The value `%` is making the div as big as 100% of itself, not the screen. The screen is relative and the browser will make an overflow-x bar if it needs to. Making the div 100% of itself will just fit the div to the inner text, not the other way around.

Comment: [how's this?](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/QbmdK/29/)  You'll just have to play with the top and bottom values of `.PopupPanel` to get it to the size you want it

Comment: @Pete- that looks like the effect I am looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're fiddling too much with the display property and you haven't defined a max-width. Something like this works:

```
.PopupPanelBG {
  display: table;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.PopupPanel {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /*text-align: center;*/
  position: relative;
}

.PopupPanel>div {
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  /*vertical-align: middle;*/
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.9;
  background-color: #e1efbb;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  overflow : auto;
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: That fixes the scrolling.  Thank you.  It does remove my vertical centering though.  Any ideas how to get that back?

Comment: Right, that wasn't clear from your question. You need that extra div to get that working. Edited answer, not perfect but gets close.

Comment: The key take away from your answer is that the inline-block I was using is what was killing the scrolling.  Thanks for pointing out that the display property is what was causing the problems.

Answer (score 5):

So... This works (with percents).

http://jsfiddle.net/Agony/QbmdK/34/

(Now with vertical alignment!)

The thing you want to note is that the wrapping `div` has a set `max-width:50%` while the `innerdiv` has a `max-width:100%`. That will hold true for any amount of data.

Comment: Not centered vertically, just like my initial answer.

Comment: Wait... Why would you need vertical centering if the `overflow-x` and `white-space:nowrap` is there...?

Comment: I don't see any nowrap in the question?

Comment: I don't either, but I see it in the answer. At any rate, you can add `vertical-align:middle;` to the `#innerdiv` CSS to align the contents vertically too, though it changes nothing since there is `nowrap`.

Comment: Not the content, but the bounding box had to be vertically centered

Comment: Ohhhhhh. Okay, that makes more sense. Well, that's not too bad. Check my updated fiddle in my answer.